# Sitefinity 8.2 - Front End Error with Rocketship Image, Cannot Figure out Source

Tags: azure, sitefinity-8

I am facing an issue in a Sitefinity application and we are seeing the following image as an error whenever we do a Content Sync between the Staging & Production environments. For reference, we are using Sitefinity V8.2 on a load-balanced environment hosted with Azure and this is a multi-site application with the Online Marketing license.

My question is this: Does anyone know what the rocketship graphic below is coming from? We are not sure and it does not appear to be an error with Sitefinity.

Here is the image: http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f22/Tj_Bode/rocketship_zpshyj8oavn.png

Answer (score 0):

The graphic is coming from Sitefinity, it is shown while the CMS restarts after the content sync.

You can see this article from the docs for more information: http://docs.sitefinity.com/application-status-pages-display-workflow